# How to calculate chance of a random line falling within a square in a grid.

Tags: calculus, probability

I'm currently trying to solve a question involving the chances of a line (length 1) falling within a square with sides of length 1.

The middlepoint of the needle is a random point within the square. The needle can be any angle of orientation.

I arrived at the equations:

$0.5 \sin(x)= y$ (where y is the vertical coordinate of the midpoint of the line)

And:

$0.5 \cos(x)= z$ (where z is the horizontal coordinate of the midpoint of the line)

But i'm having trouble combining these two, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more details and assumptions? For example, how long is the needle and what does the entire grid look like compared to the $1\times 1$ square?

Comment: The needle is 1 cm long, the grid is basically a 1x1 square. The middlepoint of the needle is a random point within the square. The needle can be any angle of orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the angle is $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$, the needle covers a distance of $\cos\theta$ along the $x$-axis and $\sin\theta$ along the $y$-axis, and so has a probability of $1-\cos\theta$ of not hitting a vertical line, a probability of $1-\sin\theta$ of not hitting a horizontal line, and a probability $(1-\cos\theta)(1-\sin\theta)$ of not hitting any line at all.  The probability you want is the average of this over all $\theta$:
$$
p=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(1-\cos\theta)(1-\sin\theta)d\theta=\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{2}(\pi-3)=1-\frac{3}{\pi}\approx 0.04507.
$$
(So the odds are not good.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I winder what is the 2/Pi for? I get the Pi is for turning angle into "percent chance", is the 2 to account for the entire 360 degrees?

Comment: No, it's to average over the range of angles $[0,\pi/2]$: $1/(\pi/2)=2/\pi$.